# Exchange 2016 Concurrent mailbox connections

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, exchange-2016

On Exchange 2016 (Version 15.0 ‎(Build 847.32)‎) we have a single mailbox that is used on 2 computers. When computer A has Outlook 2010 open, computer B can no longer open Outlook 2010. However, the exact opposite happens when you open Outlook on computer B first. Then computer A gets the error message.
The computers are stand alone and are logging in with the same domain account. However, I tried using different AD accounts and the issue persists.

Error message when trying to open Outlook while the mailbox is opened on the other computer: "Cannot open default email folders, Microsoft Exchange is not available"
However it is possible to ping the server (IP and DNS) and ping autodiscover.domainname.com

Already tried to: 
- Set Maximum concurrent connections to unlimited
- Set Maximum concurrent connections per domain to unlimited
- Remove the profile on both computers
- Restarted the Exchange server and computers
- Removed all ost files under C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook

Comment: Are you using the same AD account or are there two different accounts used (e.g. one for PC 1 and one for PC 2). Did you tried using the Outlook Cache mode? Are these real PCs or some kind of terminal server?

Comment: I updated my question: It are standalone computers and they are using the same AD account to log in.

Comment: Update: Using different AD accounts does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple areas that needs to be validated:

1. Appropriate version of Outlook 2010. In order to connect to Exchange 2016 it needs to be: Outlook 2010 SP2 and updates KB2956191 and KB2965295
   See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719(v=exchg.160).aspx).
2. You seems to be running CU5, probably should upgrade to CU6 or CU7.
   See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098(v=exchg.150).aspx).
3. On the internal network, in order to get to the CAS, SCP is used.
   Let's see the results of:

   Get-ClientAccessService | fl Name,OutlookAnywhereEnabled, AutodiscoverServiceInternalUri

Comment: Updating to CU7 resolved this issue. Thank you.